# For the Running Ragged hat, do you need 150 on each individual site, or collectively?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

The [Running Ragged hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/running-ragged) say:

> earn 150 reputation points on three different sites (not including Stack Overflow) within 15 days.

[image: running ragged]

Does this mean that you must collectively earn 150 reputation points on 3 sites, or 150 points on each individual site?

Comment: Turns out this was asked before, but it didn't come up in my searching, so perhaps this will make a good sign post anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not accumulative.

You must get 150 rep points on 3 individual Stack Exchange sites that are not Stack Overflow.

That's what makes it so challenging, and worthy of the name "Running Ragged"!